# Script optimization, primarily due to for loops [R]

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization

I have a recording of blood pressure and velocity in the resolution of 1000 Hz. During this recording i have identified periods (e.g. 1, 2, 3). The primary problem is with optimization. I have multiple recordings which are between 10 and 15 minutes in length, which results in ~1.000.000 rows.

```
            n    time pres mcav period
1           1   7.000   76 43.6      1
2           2   7.001   75 43.6      1     
3           3   7.002   73 43.6      1     
4           4   7.003   74 43.6      1     
5           5   7.004   74 43.5      1     
6           6   7.005   74 43.5      1     
...
898914 909995 916.994   84 60.8      3   
898915 909996 916.995   85 60.7      3   
898916 909997 916.996   85 60.7      3   
898917 909998 916.997   84 60.6      3   
898918 909999 916.998   83 60.4      3   
898919 910000 916.999   84 60.3      3
```

For each of these periods i would like to identify blocks (3 second periods).

```
temp <- NULL

#For loop for every period
for(i in unique(df$period)){

 #Extract the part of the df which is within the period
 temp_df <- df[df$time >= min(df$time[df$period == i]) & df$time <= max(df$time[df$period == i]),]

 #Insert "n" starting from 1 and count from there.
 temp_df$block <- temp_df$n-min(temp_df$n)+1

 #Divide this consecutive number into 3-second blocks. 
 temp_df$block <- ceiling(temp_df$block/3000)

 #Combine the dataframes for every period into one.
 temp <- rbind(temp,temp_df[,c("n","block")])
}
```

This loop is actually pretty fast, but could be optimized. Is apply and a homemade function the way to go?

Next part might be the issue. The temp-dataframe will now be merged:

```
df <- merge(df,temp,by="n",all.x=T)
```

This part takes a couple of seconds, but it results in this dataframe:

```
            n    time pres mcav period block
1           1   7.000   76 43.6      1     1
2           2   7.001   75 43.6      1     1
3           3   7.002   73 43.6      1     1
4           4   7.003   74 43.6      1     1
5           5   7.004   74 43.5      1     1
6           6   7.005   74 43.5      1     1
...
898914 909995 916.994   84 60.8      3   100
898915 909996 916.995   85 60.7      3   100
898916 909997 916.996   85 60.7      3   100
898917 909998 916.997   84 60.6      3   100
898918 909999 916.998   83 60.4      3   100
898919 910000 916.999   84 60.3      3   100
```

Comment: You can optimize a lot using `dplyr` or, particularly, `data.table`. Can you `dput()` your example data instead of posting the printout to make it reproducible?

Comment: I would really prefer to use base R, but I accept if optimization is only applicable with other packages. The 1 mio rows, cannot be exported in ```dput()```

Comment: But you can still make it minimally reproducible by selecting a few rows and then `dput`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can try `ave` like below

```
df <- within(df,block <- ave(n,period,FUN = function(x) ceiling(x/3000)))
```

Comment: I like the idea, i will try to implement this. I havent used ```ave``` before, but this mig help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, merging/binding is slow.  So let's avoid them altogether.

```
# Generate some test data
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(time=seq(7, 918, 0.001), period=rep(1:3, each=303667), pres=rnorm(911001), mcav=rnorm(911001))

# Get the period start times
periodStart <- df %>% 
                  group_by(period) %>% 
                  slice_min(time) %>% 
                  select(period, time) %>% 
                  rename(baseTime=time)
# Merge the period start times with the original dataset and derive the block definitions
# (The +0.0000001 is to make sure the first obs in each block is handled correctly.  
# Any value will do so long as it's less than your sampling frequency)
answer <- df %>% 
             left_join(periodStart, by="period") %>% 
             mutate(block=ceiling((time-baseTime + 0.0000001)/3))
answer
# A tibble: 911,001 x 6
    time period    pres   mcav baseTime block
   <dbl>  <int>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1  7         1 -0.929   0.571        7     1
 2  7.00      1 -1.47   -0.304        7     1
 3  7.00      1  0.0150  0.193        7     1
 4  7.00      1 -1.12   -0.595        7     1
 5  7.00      1  0.677  -0.571        7     1
 6  7.00      1  1.07    2.31         7     1
 7  7.01      1 -0.606  -1.16         7     1
 8  7.01      1  1.51    0.170        7     1
 9  7.01      1 -0.718  -1.76         7     1
10  7.01      1 -0.785  -0.606        7     1
# … with 910,991 more rows
```

Now let's see how quick it is

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark({
  periodStart <- df %>% group_by(period) %>% slice_min(time) %>% select(period, time) %>% rename(baseTime=time)
  answer <- df %>% left_join(periodStart, by="period") %>% mutate(block=ceiling((time-baseTime + 0.0000001)/3))
})
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 334.9331 353.9955 424.4326 364.4362 548.3301 599.6329   100
```

So just over 0.4 seconds on average.  Is that quick enough?

Comment: I tested this and this is a lot faster, but the issue is that i prefer base R. I will get back to you. Thank you!